# How to select all files from one sample?

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I have a problem figuring out how to make the input directive only select all `{samples}` files in the rule below.

```
rule MarkDup:
    input:
        expand("Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/{samples}_{lanes}_{flowcells}.merged.bam", zip,
            samples=samples['sample'],
            lanes=samples['lane'],
            flowcells=samples['flowcell']),
    output:
        bam = "Outputs/MarkDuplicates/{samples}_markedDuplicates.bam",
        metrics = "Outputs/MarkDuplicates/{samples}_markedDuplicates.metrics",
    shell:
        "gatk --java-options -Djava.io.tempdir=`pwd`/tmp \
        MarkDuplicates \
        $(echo ' {input}' | sed 's/ / --INPUT /g') \
        -O {output.bam} \
        --VALIDATION_STRINGENCY LENIENT \
        --METRICS_FILE {output.metrics} \
        --MAX_FILE_HANDLES_FOR_READ_ENDS_MAP 200000 \
        --CREATE_INDEX true \
        --TMP_DIR Outputs/MarkDuplicates/tmp"
```

Currently it will create correctly named output files, but it selects all files that match the pattern based on all wildcards. So I'm perhaps halfway there. I tried changing `{samples}` to `{{samples}}` in the input directive as such:

```
expand("Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/{{samples}}_{lanes}_{flowcells}.merged.bam", zip,
            lanes=samples['lane'],
            flowcells=samples['flowcell']),`
```

but this broke the previous rule somehow. So the solution is something like

```
input:
     "{sample}_*.bam"
```

But clearly this doesn't work.
Is it possible to collect all files that match `{sample}_*.bam` with a function and use that as input? And if so, will the function still work with `$(echo ' {input}' etc...)` in the shell directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want all the files in the directory, you can use a lambda function

```
from glob import glob

rule MarkDup:
    input:
        lambda wcs: glob('Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/%s*.bam' % wcs.samples)
    output:
        bam="Outputs/MarkDuplicates/{samples}_markedDuplicates.bam",
        metrics="Outputs/MarkDuplicates/{samples}_markedDuplicates.metrics"
    shell:
        ...
```

Just be aware that this approach can't do any checking for missing files, since it will always report that the files needed are the files that are present.  If you do need confirmation that the upstream rule has been executed, you can have the previous rule touch a flag, which you then require as input to this rule (though you don't actually use the file for anything other than enforcing execution order).

Comment: Thank you so much! This coupled with a fake rule checkpoint made it work like it should.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `zip` needs to be applied only to `{lane}` and `{flowcells}` and not to `{samples}`. In that case, use two `expand` instances can achieve that.

```
input:
    expand(expand("Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/{{samples}}_{lanes}_{flowcells}.merged.bam", 
        zip, lanes=samples['lane'], flowcells=samples['flowcell']), 
            samples=samples['sample'])
```

PS: `output.tmp` file uses `{sample}` instead of `{samples}`. Typo?

Comment: Unfortunately this still breaks the previous rule. I think it's the `{{samples}}` variable that causes it. This is the error message:

InputFunctionException in line 48 of /home/oskar/01-workspace/00-temp/GVP/Snakefile:
KeyError: 39
Wildcards:
sample=SAMPLE1
lane=L003
flowcell=FlowCellY

And the meaning of this is that it starts combining all lines instead of just line by line.

And yes, it should have been `{samples}` in the output.tmp line, it's commented out in my actual Snakefile, I just forgot to remove it here.