# How do I make this into a function for input files?

Tags: function, csv, wildcard, snakemake

**Short explanation:**

I need to gather input files based on the file name without using `expand()`, I'm trying to make a custom function based on the code below but it's not working.

**Long explanation:**

I have the following python code that closely resembles what I need to do, but that needs some fixing and adapting to snakemake:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

samples = pd.read_csv('samples.tsv', sep='\t', dtype=str).set_index(["flowcell", "sample", "lane"], drop=False)
samples.index = samples.index.set_levels([i.astype(str) for i in samples.index.levels])  # enforce str in index

filename = pd.Series(samples['sample']).unique()
rgs = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join('Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/%s*.bam' % filename)))
print(rgs)
```

I use this tsv file:

```
flowcell    sample  library lane    R1  R2
FlowCellX   SAMPLE1 libZ    L001    fastq/Sample1.R1.fastq.gz   fastq/Sample1.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellX   SAMPLE1 libZ    L002    fastq/Sample1.R1.fastq.gz   fastq/Sample1.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellX   SAMPLE1 libY    L003    fastq/Sample1.R1.fastq.gz   fastq/Sample1.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellY   SAMPLE2 libY    L003    fastq/Sample2.R1.fastq.gz   fastq/Sample2.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellX   SAMPLE2 libY    L003    fastq/Sample2.R1.fastq.gz   fastq/Sample2.R2.fastq.gz
```

And when I run the code I get this output:

```
['Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE1_L001_FlowCellX.merged.bam', 'Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE1_L002_FlowCellX.merged.bam', 'Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE1_L003_FlowCellX.merged.bam', 'Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE2_L003_FlowCellX.merged.bam', 'Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE2_L003_FlowCellY.merged.bam']
```

I think this is wrong though, it should (probably) look like this:

```
['Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE1_L001_FlowCellX.merged.bam', 'Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE1_L002_FlowCellX.merged.bam', 'Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE1_L003_FlowCellX.merged.bam']
['Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE2_L003_FlowCellX.merged.bam', 'Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/SAMPLE2_L003_FlowCellY.merged.bam']
```

I can produce the correct output with this for loop:

```
for s in pd.Series(samples['sample']).unique():
    filename = glob.glob(os.path.join('Outputs/MergeBamAlignment/%s*.bam' % s))
    print filename
```

But I understand for loops aren't allowed in python functions so that's out of the question.

So how can I produce lists (?) with the input files from each sample without using the `expand()` function but instead using a custom function? The reason `expand()` is out of the question is because the answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711807/how-to-select-all-files-from-one-sample) broke the previous rule since `{{sample}}` seems to be messing up `zip` in the previous rule's `expand()` function.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused after looking at your previous question. Isn't `{sample}` distinct for each run of the rule?  E.g., `"SAMPLE1", "SAMPLE2"` are two separate runs of the rule; in other words, you don't require all the files from *both* samples to run the rule.

Comment: Also, I expect the answer I gave to the previous question to also answer this one.  If it does, we should mark this as a duplicate question. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: "for loops aren't allowed in python functions" -> I'm not sure what you mean by that. My intuition tells me that you want a function that can return the elements that you would obtain at different moments of a for loop. You could try to use `yield` instead of `return`.

Comment: @merv yes, your answer in my other thread did the trick, thank you. This should be marked as a duplicate.
And it's correct that I wasn't specific enough when I formulated my problem description in this thread. I wanted to gather all files per sample and use them as input for MarkDuplicates to merge them per sample.